# How to fix URL with pageid example /?p= too many redirection error

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I have recently updated my WordPress to 5.5 and I encountered "too many redirection error" when I use URL with page id `/?p=1234` (previously it was working before the update). It keeps redirecting to `/1` regardless of post id number

I am using multisite and in my permalink settings I am using `/%postname%/`

Checking redirection I get this:

```
?p=1234
301 Moved Permanently
1
301 Moved Permanently
1
301 Moved Permanently
1
```

My `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
#add a trailing slash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$ 
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
#add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Any help on how to further check or solve this?

Comment: There's nothing in the `.htaccess` file you posted that would trigger this.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone looking for answers in the future, I have solved the issue by searching for

```
add_filter('redirect_canonical'
```

in all the plugins and found the culprit.